# How to run already saved files on matlab cloud from matlab mobile app of android?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

After searching Matlab support and blogs it is not at all clear to me how to run Matlab files which are already saved. Suppose I have Matlab code file 
*code1.m* on cloud and I want to run that file  and get an output from my Android device. What should I write after *>>*? How can I run those files?

Comment: What does `pwd` return on your device? I presume it defaults to the "home" directory on your cloud storage.

Comment: Yes it does give the "home" location. But can you help me to find out how to run any saved program. I can definitely find the directory but I can't run any saved program. I am sorry this question must be silly but I am not getting it

Comment: @nkjt please help me I am getting stuck in the first place.

Comment: and if you use `dir` or `ls`, can you see what directories/files you have access to? You can't just do `code1`?

Comment: Yes if I use 'ls' I can see all the files

Comment: @nkjt but can you explain the next steps?